# python prompt function that can be used a button function

Tags: python, class, command-prompt

I'm looking for any python build-in prompt that allows me to connect two classes(windows). The basic idea is that when the task in the classA is finished, the prompt appears, and the users need to press a key to start next task in classB. Hence, I'm looking for a prompt that can be used as a button function. It requires a lot changes on my canvas if I use `button function`, so I want a clean method to prompt it.

I have looked at tkinter `messagebox`, but it doesn't allow me to have such function. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just put a prompt in the function that starts the task from ClassA?

Comment: woah two upvotes? 0_o

Comment: @Morb could you elaborate a little please? I'm sorry that I don't really get what you mean by that. Thanks!

Comment: For example, to start the task in ClassA, you call something like `classA.startTask()` and to call the one in ClassB, you call `classB.startTask()`. You could add `raw_input('Press any key to start Task B')` between the two calls. It will pause and wait for the user to press enter.

Comment: @Morb thanks for you suggestion! One more dumb question if you don't mind, I uses `super class` as ClassB inherits from ClassA. Does it change anything on the method you provided?

Comment: it shouldn't change anything